# Puling big data from Web Service in Android efficiently

Tags: android, web-services, database-performance

I am having one web service in which i have list of countries, state and corresponding cities of it. Now I am little bit confused in pulling this data in my Android app. Right now I have only 2(USA,Canada) Country data with me but it might be increased in future. Also I have list of state in this country and yes the cities in every state.

I have one splash screen in my app in which I have written the logic of getting country and on the basis of that i am getting state and then cities for every state. But its long process and if i publish this a user will be frustrated by waiting time. So I don't want to use this way which takes longer time for pulling data. Is there any other way or suggestion for me to achieve this.

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to perform any web data downloading (and uploading), it works in the background and does not block UI thread, so your user won't notice.

also, it might be a good idea to supply default country/city data along with your application and then download only changes/updates.

Comment: Yes I am using the Async Task. But my question is that I am having 3 spinner for Country, State and City. And in splash screen i am fetching this data and in the next screen I am displaying that. But in fetching this data it takes longer time. So I would like to know that how to save this waiting time for the user. Is there any suggestion or tips for this.

Comment: as i said before, 1) supply default data along with your app, so you may show something straight away, there are about 200 countries and maybe about 1000 large cities, this data won't take much space. 2) save downloaded data to the device, then next time your application starts you don't have to access web, but load the data from the disk, that takes about 300-500ms in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Service or intent-service, to download the data in background. and when the download is complete you can display the downloaded data using onbind. service runs on a seperate thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could simple use the system DownloadManager to get the files from your sources and later process them. The DownloadManager will even inform you when the file is fully downloaded.

Take a look a https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Internet/Download/src/com/commonsware/android/download/DownloadDemo.java for a simple example code using DownloadManager.